# How to create multilevel listview/recyclerview with navigation

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview

I am new to android development. I got the design from client as show in the image bellow. can anyone suggest  me how to create view like this?. I have created the expandable recycler view but not getting how to create multilevel listview.

Comment: [Check](https://github.com/bignerdranch/expandable-recycler-view) this.

Comment: U can take different row... For Different view According to You Views... If take Dynamically .....

Comment: Can you please elaborate more?

Answer (score 2):

You can use for each entry (list item) , a framelayout since it allows overlapping easily , have an image view inside it to take all the available space , and a Relative layout to define the other elements like the number, the color below it, etc... and then wrap this Relative layout with a Linear Layout ; the Relative layout would be first element , and then the Recycler/List View would be the second element below the relative , at first it is `visibility="gone"` , and on relative layout clicked ... `relative.setVisibilty(View.VISIBLE)` and so on ...

What you want is a bit more complex than what i said , but either way this is a good headstart !